# JavaFX cell styling

Tags: javafx

I have looked at other questions, yet they do not satisfy my question

I want specific cells to have red color in my treeview, and I use

```
public void updateView()
{
    treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new TreeCell<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
            }
            else {
                for(ArrayList<TreeItem> x :Signals)
                {
                    for(TreeItem z: x)
                    {
                        if(z.getValue().equals(item))
                        {
                            setText(item);
                            setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red");
                        }
                        else{ setText(item);}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried formatting it, it just does not work for me, sorry.
What happens is that is messes up my treeView table. See pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVVWS.jpg

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that cells are reused; you need to remove the style and/or text from the cell, if a unmarked item is assigned to the cell /  the cell becomes empty. Furthermore the text needs to be assigned only once:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new TreeCell<String>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setStyle(null);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText("");
        } else {
            setText(item);

            // apply style, if a TreeItem containing the same value as the item is found in Signals
            outer: for(List<TreeItem> x : Signals) {
                for(TreeItem z: x) {
                    if(z.getValue().equals(item)) {
                        setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red");
                        break outer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```